# Why do I get a Key Error for 'post' in PostListView

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I don't know why I got a Key Error message (KeyError at /   'post') when I `def get_context_data` in `PostListView`. But that was totally fine when I just `def get_context_data` in `PostListDetailView`.

Views.py

```
def home(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_liked = True
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all(),
        'is_liked': is_liked,
        'total_likes': post.total_likes(),
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


def like_post(request):   # post like
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True

    return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
    is_liked = False

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        post = context['post']
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            context['is_liked'] = True
        return context


class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    is_liked = False

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        post = context['post']
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            context['is_liked'] = True
        return context
```

Below is the full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 3.0.4
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['blog.apps.BlogConfig',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/louisglenn/PycharmProjects/Pblog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/louisglenn/PycharmProjects/Pblog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/louisglenn/PycharmProjects/Pblog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/louisglenn/PycharmProjects/Pblog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/louisglenn/PycharmProjects/Pblog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/louisglenn/PycharmProjects/Pblog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 157, in get
    context = self.get_context_data()
  File "/Users/louisglenn/PycharmProjects/Pblog/blog/views.py", line 50, in get_context_data
    post = context['post']

Exception Type: KeyError at /
Exception Value: 'post'
```

But when I changed my key to 'object_list', There is a new error 'AttributeError at /
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'likes'

```
__class__   
<class 'blog.views.PostListView'>
context 
{'is_paginated': True,
 'object_list': <QuerySet [<Post: aasd>, <Post: asd>, <Post: ads>, <Post: asd>, <Post: asd>]>,
 'page_obj': <Page 1 of 3>,
 'paginator': <django.core.paginator.Paginator object at 0x102f6f640>,
 'posts': <QuerySet [<Post: aasd>, <Post: asd>, <Post: ads>, <Post: asd>, <Post: asd>]>,
 'view': <blog.views.PostListView object at 0x102f6f940>}
kwargs  
{}
post    
<QuerySet [<Post: aasd>, <Post: asd>, <Post: ads>, <Post: asd>, <Post: asd>]>
self    
<blog.views.PostListView object at 0x102f6f940>
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: @Chase added, thanks

Comment: changing `post = context['post']` to `post = context['object_list']` will not give you what you want. Doing `.likes` on `post` now is invalid because `context['object_list']` does not have that attribute. I do see there is a key named `'posts'` in there, perhaps that's what you need? I suggest you get familiar with the basics of python dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your context data doesn't have the key `post`, so this doesn't work

```py
post = context['post']
```

Keep in mind that `DetailView`'s `get_context_data` (the one being used in `PostDetailView`) might not be the exact same as `ListView`'s `get_context_data` (the one being used in `PostListView`)

This line in `PostDetailView` and `PostListView` do not do the same thing-

```py
context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Since `super` refers to different classes for these 2. In case of `PostDetailView`, it's `DetailView` and in case of `PostListView`, it's `ListView` - hence `context` will not be the same across both functions.

You should check the `context` variable in each of those 2 different `get_context_data` using debugging, and find out which key you actually want.

Edit: To elaborate on how to debug, in case you're using VSCode, [here's](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) a quick guide on how to get started.

If you're on Pycharm, [here's](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html) another quick guide on that!

After you start the debugging sense, you'll be able to setup breakpoints (by clicking next to the line numbers) and your code will *pause* in this breakpoints. You can then simply use the panels on the left (on VSCode) or bottom (on Pycharm) to view each variable value.

Comment: @LouisGlenn I added a quickstart for that

Comment: Thanks @Chase, but I have checked the dubug and changed the key to object_list, but there is a new error `AttributeError at /
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'likes'`. I have attached the local_var details under the error traceback. Thanks